# How to add custom stop word list to StopWordsRemover

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, text-mining, stop-words

I am using pyspark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover class on my pyspark dataframe. It has ID and Text column. In addition to default stop word list provided, I would like to add my own custom list to remove all numeric values from string.

I can see there is a method provided to add setStopWords for this class. I think I'm struggling with the proper syntax to use this method.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.ml.feature import * 

a = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered")
b = a.transform(df)
```

The above code gives me expected results in the filtered column but it only removes / stops standard words. I'm looking for a method to add my own custom list which would have more words and numeric values that I wish to filter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify it with this :

```
stopwordList = ["word1","word2","word3"]

StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered" ,stopWords=stopwordList)
```

### A small Note:

The above solution replaces the original list of stop words with the list we supplied.
If you want to add your own stopwords in addition to the existing/predefined stopwords, then we need to append the list with the original list before passing into StopWordsRemover() as a parameter. We transform to set to remove any duplicate.

> `stopwordList = ["word1","word2","word3"]`
>   `stopwordList.extend(StopWordsRemover().getStopWords())`
>   `stopwordList = list(set(stopwordList))#optionnal`
>  
>   `StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered" ,stopWords=stopwordList)`

Comment: Adding this note to on how to add all numeric values to StopWrodList: num_list=range(0,99999)
stopwordList=map(str,num_list)

Comment: I don't think it's wise to use such a list since for every token it has to loop over every element of the list and compare it with the token. I would suggest using regex such as ``` re.sub(r"/d+", "", text) ```. it's way more efficient

Comment: And what if I don't have a tiny list, but a huge txt with custom words? I'm having trouble with this because the txt is read as a dataFrame in pyspark and this `,stopWords=` argument won't  take dataframes :(